# Which part should I read?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Question no $1$ >   Let $D$ denote the closed unit disc and let $S^1$ denote the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$Let $E=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}\le 1\}$
Which of the following statements are true?

> a)If $f:E\to E$ is continuous, than there exists $x\in E$ such that $f(x)=x$.
>
> b)If $f:D\to S^1$ is continuous, than there exists $x\in S^1$ such that $f(x)=x$.
>
> c)If $f:S^1\to S^1$ is continuous, than there exists $x\in S^1$ such that $f(x)=x$.

Question no - 2 >
Let V and W be normed linear spaces and let T : V → W be a continuous linear operator. Let B be the closed unit ball in V . In which of the following cases is T(B) compact?

$a.$ $V = C_1[0,1]$,$W = C[0,1]$ and $T(f) = f$.

b. $V = W = `_2$ and $T(x) = (0,x_1,x_2,···)$, where $x = (x_n) ∈ `2$.

c. $V = W = `2$ and $T(x) = (x_1,x_2,···,x_10,0,···,0,···)$, where $x = (x_n) ∈ `2$.

Question no 3> For $x = (x_n) ∈ `2$, deﬁne $T(x) = (0,x_1,x_2,···)$ and $S(x) = (x_2,x_3,···)$. Which of the following statements are true?

a. norm($T$) = norm($S$) = $1$.

b. If $A : `2 → `2$ is a continuous linear operator such that norm$(A−T)$ < $1$, then $SA$ is invertible.

c. If $A$ is as above, then $A$ is not invertible.

Actually these questions were given in Topology Section of a PH.D screening Test Question. I have read up to Local Compactness from Mukresh. But I don't think I am eligible to solve those questions. Can you please let me know how much should I read from Mukresh to be able to answer those questions?

It will help me to set my target. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to the book? The closest I know of to your book is Munkres’ text.

Comment: Yes I am reading Mukresh. But How much I have to read to be able to answer those questions?

Comment: I  love to read Mukresh. But How much should I read? Bcoz I have an exam after two Months.@Clayton

Comment: used simple logics for Question 1. as  inside big  circle u  put  any ball  as it will not fixed ....but  it in  inside big closed disc   ,it will fixed   because   inside circle there  is   empty  buts   discs  is not   so answer  will be option a) and B)

Comment: @Cmi it depend upon on ur understanding as  i have already  finished  Munkre book in 3 months

Comment: Congrats...But My question was how much should I read to be able to answer those questions?@Michael

Comment: Read Mukresh rigorously. You will get to know.

Comment: But How much? It would really help me to understand how far I am from my destination..@sani

Comment: (1a) is true by Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem, which is not an obvious theorem.

Comment: In (2a), $T(V)=V$,...and $V$ is dense in, but not equal to $W.$ So $V$ is not a closed subset of $W,$ and since $W$ is a Hausdorff space, $V$ is not compact

Comment: What does ${^,}2$ mean? I've never seen it before.

Comment: Dear@DanielWainfleet I did not ask the answer of the question. Can u please read the question one more time?

Comment: I know. I am not familiar with that book. The $topics$ in my comments were my point.